# Servlets sending request to URL?

Tags: servlets, oauth

I am totally new to servlets.I am trying to send a request to google to get a token.I tried many sources but all i can get is "send request to a url with some parameters". My question is how can we send request to a url by passing few parameters using servlets..please help..

Comment: First you should say how are you making the request.

Comment: from what i read.i have to make a request to https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken by passing query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameter along with url using Query String. A URL with Query String will look like this:

```
http://google.com/search?a=b&c=d
```

Where `a & c` are parameters which will have `b & d` values respectively.

Comment: i have to send request to https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken with parameters like my client id etc...should i write the entire url??because i have to pass many params

Comment: Yes you have to give the entire url with query string if you are required to send parameters.

Comment: can u give me an example code to send a request..where should i put this url

Comment: can you say how to send parameters in to headers not as a query?